# How do check that applications on two different Servers are using the same version of a dll?

Tags: windows, dll

How I have two programs that use the same dll on different servers.  How do I check that both servers are using the same dll version? In this case, I want to make sure Exchange and Blackberry Enterprise Server are using the same version of a dll.

Sorry, I didn't really ask this question right the first time.

Comment: What do you mean by "Registered DLLs"? Are we talking about the COM registry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `tasklist /M` command to list all DLL modules loaded for a specific process

**edit:** If you want to show the specific version of a DLL used by a process, I recommand using the graphical tool [Process Explorer](http://live.sysinternals.com/procexp.exe) from Sysinternals. Once you run the tool, click on a specific process and it will gives you the list of DLLs (with version) that are hooked to this process.

Answer (score 0):

Ummm... look at the file information? It's on the Details or Version tab of the file properties, depending on which version of Windows you're running.